# SELECT with COUNT from the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, count

I have this table:

```
id   |                timestamp            |     type    |    
-----+-------------------------------------+-------------+
 175 | 2013-02-28 00:00                    |         1   |
 176 | 2013-02-28 00:00                    |         1   |
 177 | 2013-02-28 00:00                    |         2   |
 178 | 2013-02-28 00:00                    |         2   |
 179 | 2013-02-28 00:00                    |         1   |
 180 | 2013-02-28 00:00                    |         1   |
 181 | 2013-03-01 00:00                    |         10  |
 182 | 2013-03-01 00:00                    |         2   |
 183 | 2013-03-01 00:00                    |         2   |
 184 | 2013-03-01 00:00                    |         1   |
```

I'm trying to do a SELECT, where I get, for example the line with id = 181 and timestamp 2013-03-01 00:00, and return a type's count for each type from a week before. I'm trying to do the return something like:

```
 id  |                timestamp            |     type    | type1 | type2 | type3 |
-----+-------------------------------------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+
 181 | 2013-03-01 00:00                    |         10  |   4   |   2   |   0   |
```

I did this query:

```
SELECT timestamp, type, 
(SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN 1 END) AS types FROM i
    WHERE timestamp BETWEEN (SELECT date_trunc('week', timestamp) - interval '7 days') AND ((SELECT date_trunc('week', timestamp) - interval '7 days') + interval '7 days')
    GROUP BY timestamp, type)
FROM i 
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2013-03-01' AND '2013-03-01' AND i.tipo = '4'
GROUP BY timestamp, type
```

But this query give me the error:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression 
Dunno if there is a way to put this rows returned as columns.

Any ideas or suggestion?

Comment: Sound like you want a pivot table, which is not very easy in MySQL: http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html

Comment: @MichaelDunlap: thanks! You've got me in a direction, as I'm using postgres, I'll look for something like crosstab or crosstab_hash.

Answer (score 0):

To get your starting date, I just used a subquery.
If you have a relatively small set of type values, you can use a `CASE` statement to count each type:

```
count(case when `type` = 1 then t1.`id` else null end) as Type1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1618c4/19)

```
select
t2.`id`,
count(case when `type` = 1 then t1.`id` else null end) as Type1,
count(case when `type` = 2 then t1.`id` else null end) as Type2
from
i t1,
(select
 `id`,
`timestamp` as ts
from
i
where
`id` = 181 ) t2
where
timestamp
between date_add(t2.ts, interval -7 day) and t2.ts
and t1.id < 181
group by
t2.`id`
```

Comment: I have 40 types, so I will have to do 40 counts?

Comment: I think in theory you can use MySQL's version of dynamic SQL to build a query for a pivot table.  Check the link in Michael's comment above.  But really, I would try and handle pivots in my presentation layer.

Comment: I'll try to use Michael's idea, but I'm using postgres. I found something like crosstab or crosstab_hash.